# sqlplus in linux not returning result

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am getting "no rows selected" from sqlplus via linux but I do get the correct records from sqldeveloper.

query used:

```
SELECT status_msg 
FROM t_app_job_status 
where INTERFACE_NAME in ('ISYIN') 
and BUSINESS_DATE=(to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')-5) 
and RUN_DATE like '%01%';
```

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a VARCHAR column? That is a really bad idea

Comment: And `to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')-5` is completely wrong. If at all you want `to_char(sysdate - 5,'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: issue a COMMIT in SQL Developer and see what happens in your SQLPlus call